# applying condition for not collapsing menu in odoo 13 xml

Tags: python, odoo

here is collapsing menu code but i want to applying condition for some menu for not collapsing. how can i use condition for not collapsing in some menu. Please anyone help me. here is odoo 13 version xml file. i want to use condition for one menu that menu should not be collapsing how can i do that.

class dashboard(http.Controller):
@http.route('/dashboard', website=True, auth='public')
def student_dashboard(self, **kwargs):
# return "Hello World"

```
    return request.render("dashboard.student_dashboard_view", {
        'menus': {
            'Assignment': [
                'Assignment',
                'Assignment Submission',
                'Submitted Assignment List',
            ],
            'Exam/Quiz': [
                'Exam',
                'Quiz',
            ],
            'Meeting & Counseling': [
                'Online Meeting',
                'Meeting Details',

            ],
            'Programs and Registration': [
                'Course List',
                'Timetable',
                'Attendance',
                'Student progress',
                'Course Registration',
                'Programs',
            ],
            'Purchase': [
                'Invoice',
                'Ticket',
                'Sales Orders',
            ],
            'Hall Management': [

            ],
            'Alumni Segment': [
                'Alumni Job',
                'Certificates',

            ],
            'Library & Media': [
                'Library-All Media Details',
                'Media Purchase List',
                'Media Queue List',

            ],

        }
    })
```

```
<template id="student_dashboard_view" name="student_dashboard">
    <data>
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard/static/src/css/style.css"/>
        </xpath>


    </data>
    <t t-call="website.layout">

        <t t-set="pageName" t-value="'homepage'"/>
        <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
            <section class="s_faq_collapse pt32 pb32 o_colored_level" data-snippet="s_faq_collapse"
                     data-name="Accordion" style="background-image: none;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="myCollapse1639212344926" class="accordion" role="tablist">
                        <t t-foreach="menus" t-as="menu">
                            <div class="card bg-white" data-name="Item">
                                <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true"
                                   class="card-header o_default_snippet_text text-uppercase"
                                   t-att-data-target="'#'+menu.replace(' ', '').replace('&amp;', '').replace('/', '')">
                                    <t t-esc="menu"/>
                                </a>
                                <div class="collapse show" data-parent="#myCollapse1639212344926" role="tabpanel"
                                     t-att-id="menu.replace(' ', '').replace('&amp;', '').replace('/', '')">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p>
                                            <ul>
                                                <t t-foreach="menus[menu]" t-as="item">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#" role="tab">
                                                            <t t-esc="item"/>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </t>
                                            </ul>

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </t>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="header text-uppercase">Graduation Timeline</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="main-container">

                    <div class="text-wrapper right">

                        <div class="content text-uppercase ">

                            <h3>Thesis Proposal</h3>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-wrapper right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Qualifying Test</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-wrapper right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Nomination And Intention to Submit</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-wrapper right">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Softbound submission</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrapper right">

                        <div class="content">

                            <h3>Viva</h3>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrapper right">

                        <div class="content">

                            <h3>Hardbound submission</h3>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Hey - this is a little hard to understand at the moment. It'd be helpful if you could remove as much extra code as possible while still generating the error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).